# How to set values to multiple buttons or labels at once?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to set, for instance, `.isHidden` to multiple buttons at once, instead of:

```
button1.isHidden = true    
button2.isHidden = true    
button3.isHidden = true
```

Something like: `button1, button2, button3.isHidden = true`.

Comment: It seems like putting the buttons in an array makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put them in an array and iterate through the array.

```
[button1, button2, button3].forEach {
    $0.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @ukim's answer, you can use an **Outlet Collection**.

In you storyboard, drag from your first button and select **Outlet Collection** rather than **Outlet** as you would normally do.

[image]

Which gives you…

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
```

Then connect all your other buttons to the same `@IBOutlet`

You can then say

```
buttons.forEach {
    $0.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also create `Array` extension. It also make more sense to constraint element type to `UIButton`, such that you can't call it for any other type of array.

Something like this,

```
extension Array where Element == UIView {

    func show() {
        forEach { $0.isHidden = false }
    }

    func hide() {
        forEach { $0.isHidden = true }
    }
}
```

Then, using it like so,

```
[button1, button2, button3].hide() // hide buttons
[button1, button2, button3].show() // show
```

Extending collection makes more sense in this case, which gives more flexibility as the hide / show could be used with ArraySlices then.

Here is how you would do this,

```
extension Collection where Element: UIView {
    func show() {
        forEach { $0.isHidden = false }
    }

    func hide() {
        forEach { $0.isHidden = true }
    }

    func toggleVisibility() {
        forEach { $0.isHidden = !$0.isHidden }
    }
}
```

And with this you can do some cool thing like,

```
// hide all but not first
myArrayOfButtons.dropFirst().hide()

// hide buttons in indexes 0 to 1
myArrayOfButtons[0 ... 1].hide()

// show all buttons but not last
myArrayOfButtons.dropLast().show()

// hide first 2 buttons
myArrayOfButtons.prefix(2).hide()

// show last button
myArrayOfButtons.suffix(1).show()

// toggle visibility of first 2 
myArrayOfButtons.prefix(2).toggleVisibility()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also create an IBOutlet collection

```
@IBOutlet var multiButtons: [UIButton]!
```

Do do this: when you control-drag from the button to the code, select Outlet collection ; then control drag other buttons to this outlet collection.

Now, you can

```
for button in multiButtons {
  button.isHidden = true 
}
```